# Http Request. How to get png name? Spring Boot

Tags: html, web-applications, header, spring-boot, png

I've a web app. I have a png file in `/src/main/resources/static/images/Head.png`.

I want to do a http request to it to obtain this png file (`localhost:8080/images/Head.png`).

`ResponseEntity<byte[]> entity = new TestRestTemplate().getForEntity("http://localhost/images/Head.png", byte[].class);`

And I want to know what is the name of this png file.

Im trying with some code, but it doesn't work.

For example, using `entity.getHeaders().toString()` I obtain:

`Server=[Apache-Coyote/1.1], Last-Modified=[Mon, 28 Sep 2015 22:03:31 GMT], Content-Type=[image/png;charset=UTF-8], Content-Length=[442526], Date=[Tue, 29 Sep 2015 21:02:11 GMT]`

But there is no information of the name file.

How can I get this name file? You can check my code [here](https://github.com/Santi-7/hello).

Thanks

Comment: I'm confused. You have to know the file's name to send the request. Why do you need the find the name elsewhere?

Comment: I want to do a test that confirms that the png file obtained by the http request is the png file that i should have received.

For example, I have done another test that confirms that the file obtained is a png file:
`assertEquals("Wrong content type:\n", MediaType.valueOf("image/png;charset=UTF-8"),  entity.getHeaders().getContentType());`

Comment: @SantiGil "I want to do a test that confirms that the png file obtained by the http request is the png file that i should have received." Why? What purpose would this serve, apart from telling you that your web server is working correctly (how unusual) or not (in which case you've got bigger problems)?

Comment: It's just a work for my grade, suggested by my teacher as an extra mark, and not an upgrade for my web app. The purpose is what you say, to know that the image is correctly served.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot get the filename unless you pass it through as an additional parameter or header in the original upload. HTTP does not know or care about filesystems and anything associated with them.

Comment: How can I ensure then that the file obtained is the png file I wanted?

Comment: @SantiGil The simplest and most reliable would be to use JavaScript to generate a hash string of the content of the image, and upload that hash to the server. Then compare the uploaded hash, with the hash of the same image that's generated by the server. If they match, you know with a high degree of certainty that you're dealing with the same file, because you are comparing the actual *content* and not just the filename.

Comment: Wouldn't we have the same problem? How can i ensure that the hash uploaded to server (which later I have to request), is the hash I wanted?